# Android Python MySQL Datetime Parsing

Tags: java, android, python, mysql, datetime

I need to pass datetimes between an android client, a python server and a mysql server.

It should work the following:

- the android client sends the exact time from the client to the cherrypy python server (I guess the datetime object should be sent as a string?)
- the server has to parse this string into something useful to work with as a datetime object

Now there a two cases:

1. the datetime object should be written into a mysql database (there is an attribute of type DATETIME in the related database table)
2. the server should retrieve a datetime from the mysql database and compare it with the parsed datetime object

After some background processes finished their work with the python datetime objects as input parameters, a new datetime object should be passed back to the android client

Does anyone know some good solution for solving these problems?

Comment: Are timezones going to be involved?

Comment: Yes. The App is designed to support multiple languages, thus different timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best format for transferring datetime values is the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601); they come in the format `YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS+tz:tz`, where the `T` is optional.

Python's `datetime.datetime` class can parse these with a simple extra module (see [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)). Output is just as easy with the [`.isoformat()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).

MySQL's DATETIME column type only deals with UTC values, but by default accepts ISO 8601 datetime strings (with a space instead of a `T`), so you'd have to cast your datetime objects to UTC (example with iso8601 module mentioned above):

```
import iso8601
utciso8601 = dt.astimezone(iso8601.iso8601.UTC).isoformat(' ')[:19]
```

I'd insert the timezone offset into the database too; simply use the [`tzname()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.tzname) to retrieve it from the `datetime` object, then parse it out again when loading from MySQL with the `iso8601.iso8601.parse_timezone()` function.

```
# insertion:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dates VALUES(?, ?)', utciso8601, dt.tzname())

# querying
for row in query:
    timezone = iso8601.iso8601.parse_timezone(row[1])
    utcdt = iso8601.parse_date(row[0])
    dt = utcdt.astimezone(timezone)
```

I don't know how well Android deals with dates and times, but surely it can handle ISO 8601 formats just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To use objects in terms of datetime objects in android applications, you have to use classes from the java.util package (that is to say, you can use everything from the Java SDK for your android app). For now I get the actual datetime with the help of an GregorianCalendar object.